# how to solve can not find module 'through2' error while installing react using npx ... node version 18.3.0 & npm version 8.13.2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

npx create-react-app ./epharma/
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'through2'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\MERNStack\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\hyperquest\index.js
- C:\Users\MERNStack\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js
- C:\Users\MERNStack\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MERNStack\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\hyperquest\index.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\MERNStack\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\hyperquest\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\MERNStack\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\createReactApp.js',
    'C:\\Users\\MERNStack\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

Node.js v18.13.0